# How to get image from clipboard by clicking button? in Js code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have created a paste button, I want to click the paste button and the image will be pasted.  But it is not happening.  It is only pasted by pressing ctrl+v.  If you click on the paste button, the image will be pasted, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To get image from the clipboard, you could use the `navigator.clipboard.read()` method to get the clipboardItem. Refer the following sample:

_Host.cshtml:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace BlazorApp1.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorApp1.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html-to-image/1.11.11/html-to-image.min.js" integrity="sha512-7tWCgq9tTYS/QkGVyKrtLpqAoMV9XIUxoou+sPUypsaZx56cYR/qio84fPK9EvJJtKvJEwt7vkn6je5UVzGevw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function CopyClick(image) {
            const $testimage = document.querySelector(image); 
            htmlToImage
                .toBlob($testimage)
                .then(function (blob) {
                    return navigator.clipboard.write([
                        new ClipboardItem({
                            [blob.type]: blob
                        })
                    ]);
                })
                .then(
                    () => {
                        console.log("copy success");
                    },
                    (err) => {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                );
        };
        function PasteClick(imagecontainer) {
            console.log("Paste image"); 
            parseClipboardData(imagecontainer);
        }; 
        async function parseClipboardData(imagecontainer) {
            const items = await navigator.clipboard.read().catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
            console.log("items:", items);
            for (let item of items) {
                console.log("item.type", item.types);
                for (let type of item.types) {
                    const result = handleImage(imagecontainer, type, item) || handleText(imagecontainer, type, item);
                    if (result) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // parse image file
        function handleImage(imagecontainer,type, clipboardItem) {
            if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                clipboardItem.getType(type).then((imageBlob) => {
                    const image = `<img src="${window.URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob)}" />`;
                    const $container = document.querySelector(imagecontainer);
                    $container.innerHTML = image;
                });
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        function handleText(imagecontainer, type, clipboardItem) {
            if (type === "text/plain") {
                clipboardItem
                    .getType(type)
                    .then((blob) => blob.text())
                    .then((text) => {
                        const p = `<p>${text}</p>`;
                        const $container = document.querySelector(imagecontainer);
                        $container.innerHTML = p;
                    });
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CopyPasteImage.razor components:

```
@page "/copypasteimage"
@inject IJSRuntime JS
<h3>CopyPasteImage</h3>
<style>
    .imagecontainer {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 2rem;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

        .imagecontainer img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
</style>
<h2>Clipboard</h2>
<p>
    <button class="copy" @onclick="CopyClickEvent">Copy as an image</button>
    <button class="paste" @onclick="PasteClickEvent">Paste</button>
</p>
<div class="imagecontainer">
</div>

<p>
    image for testing:
    <br />
    <img class="testimage" src="/images/Image2.jpg" alt="">
</p>
@code {
    public async Task CopyClickEvent()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("CopyClick", ".testimage");
    }
    public async Task PasteClickEvent()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("PasteClick", ".imagecontainer");
    }
}
```

The result as below: click the copy button, it will copy the image to clipboard, then after clicking the Paste button, it will get image from the clipboard and display the image.

[image]